# TypeScript/Angular/Firebase - Should "Failed to load resource" error be caught and fixed?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, error-handling

The program works appropriately when a new user is needed to be registered in the database. However, when trying to register with an already used email, `auth/email-already-in-use` error is thrown and is caught. Furthermore, I still get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`. Do I have to worry about fixing this? If yes, how so?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from '@angular/fire/auth';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private auth: Auth) {}

  async register(email: string, password: string) {
    let user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        return user;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          console.log('The email address is already in use');
        } else {
          console.log('OOPS!');
        }
        return null;
      });
    return user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth // Inject Firebase auth service
  ) {}
  // Sign up with email/password
    async register(email: string, password: string) {
    let user = await this.afAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        return result.user;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.message=== 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          console.log('The email address is already in use');
        } else {
          console.log('OOPS!');
        }
        return null;
      });
  }
  return user;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to not use `compact` as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#about_the_compat_libraries) suggests: the compat libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version (such as version 10 or version 11). Your ultimate goal is to remove compat code and keep only version 9 modular-style code in your app.

Comment: have you checked if the password is well recovered ?

Comment: This is the registration logic. In the case where you are referring to `auth/invalid-email` or `auth/weak-password`, then the `else` clause will execute. However, the output `'The email address is already in use'` will be displayed on screen. The idea is that everything entered is valid but the email address has already been used before.

Comment: Can I have a picture of the error please?

Comment: After playing around with it, I now get the following [error](https://i.postimg.cc/g0W4St8T/image.png). Should I worry about it?

Comment: the picture you sent me contains a link like https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]

and this link is used in the anonymous sign-in
 you can enable user anonymous sign-in for this project.

Comment: enable user anonymous sign-in for this project and try again

Comment: A useful link https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signUp